# Shifting a __m128i using _mm_slli_epi64

Tags: c, sse

I am trying to use `_mm_slli_epi64` to shift a `_m128i` by one position. What I don't understand is, that the following code does not give me an all-zeroes output as I expected, but rather prints `0x00010000000000000000000000000000`. What might be wrong?

```
__m128i z = _mm_setr_epi8(0x80,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
printblock("z = ", z);
z = _mm_slli_epi64(z, 1);
printblock("z = ", z);
return;
```

Comment: I have no idea what I'm doing, but http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2khb9c7k(v=vs.90).aspx says they're signed integers? Is 0x80 an allowable value?

Comment: I believe the `__m128i` type is unsigned, and it says in MSDN that `_mm_slli_epi64` operates on signed or unsigned

Comment: The arguments to _mm_setr_epi8 are little-endian, not big-endian as you expected.  0x80 is the low byte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all it shouldn't give you an all-zeroes result, because you are not setting the register to `0x80...0` as you might think, but to `0x0...080`, since [`_mm_setr_epi8`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/2khb9c7k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) puts the first (leftmost) operand into the least significant byte of the register.

Then after the shift, the result is `0x0...0100`. Your output routine is then probably messing up the byte order, too, which results in your strange output.

Comment: Yeah, you see, I am thoroughly confused. Because I am also using the AES/NI instructions, and when I do `__m128i x = _mm_setr_epi8(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1)` and encrypt I get the correct test vector comparing with other AES implementations for encrypting "00.....01", but if I use `_mm_set_epi8`  I get a wrong result.

Answer (score 4):

`_mm_slli_epi64` shifts each 64 bit integer left by the given number of bits. You have two 64 bit integers in your `__m128i`:

```
0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000080
```

and so when you shift each one left by one bit you get:

```
0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000100
```